# How to properly make a bitwise shift in this 3 cases?

Tags: bit, bit-shift, shift

I am revising some of my learning resources and I have came across 2 examples that are somehow tricky for me.

1) The result of bitwise shift for an int value **0x80000000>>8** is **0x800000**.
How to make 8 shifts right when number of digits after 0x is equal to '8'?

2) The result of bitwise shift for an int value **0xff00<<8** is **0xff0000**.
How to make a proper bitwise 8 shifts left when number of digits after 0x is only equal to 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary equivalent of `0x80000000` is `10000000000000000000000000000000`.
So shifting it by 8 bits leads to a binary number `100000000000000000000000` which is `0x800000`.

The binary equivalent of `0xff00` is `0b1111111100000000`. Shifting it by 8 bits leads to `0b111111110000000000000000`.

The left shift and right shift actually work on the binary equivalent of the numbers and not on the hexadecimal equivalent. As you can see the binary equivalent has more digits than hexadecimal equivalent.

However suppose we were to do `0x80000000 >> 100` then 100 shifts would be more than the number of binary digits, so the result would be `0x0`.

In the left shift case, additional zeros are added with each left shift operation.

Comment: Wow! Great explanation, now it's so clear. Thank you very much!